# To show an element in the sprectum of a matrix $M$ is negative in the spectrum of $-M$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $V$ be a Banach space , $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, an operator $H
>  \in \mathbb{B}(V \oplus V)$ in a form of  \begin{align} H = 
>  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & x \\ y & 0  \end{pmatrix} \end{align}
>
> Show that $\lambda \in \Lambda(H)$ if and only if $-\lambda \in
>  \Lambda(-H)$.
>
> (Hint: To find an operator $T$ such that $THT^{-1} = -H$)

$\lambda \in \Lambda(H)$ => $-\lambda \in \Lambda(-H)$

If $\lambda \in \Lambda(H)$ then $H - \lambda I$ is not invertible, and $(H - \lambda I)T = 0$ for some nonzero $T$. That is, $H T = \lambda T$, $- H T = - \lambda T$. I have totally no idea to continue. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have not yet used the given form of $H$.

Comment: Note: just because an operator (here $H-\lambda I$) is not invertible, it does not mean that you can find an element in the kernel, so your approach contains a mistake.
Have you tried using the hint? What happens?

Answer (score 1):

This is elementary: an operator $T$ is invertible if and only if $-T$ is invertible. Now

> $H-\lambda I$ is not invertible if and only if $(-H)-(-\lambda)I$ is not invertible

Therefore $\lambda$ belongs to the spectrum of $H$ if and only if $-\lambda$ belongs to the spectrum of $-H$.

For a proof with the operator $T$ such that $THT^{-1}=-H$, I suggest
$$
T=\begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & -I \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $I$ is the identity on $V$.